# Class attributes not passing to objects

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm trying to create a very basic RPG-like game where you select a character, give that character a weapon, and then tell it to attack another character with damage based on the stats of the character and the weapon. The `weapon` class belongs to a top level class called `Equip`. When I try to set an attack damage variable that incorporates the weapon's stats, however, I get:

```
'Char' object has no attribute 'weapon.'
```

I have the `Char` class `weapon` value set to `None` as default. But below, I have given the character (`dean`) a weapon by using `dean.weapon = sword` (which is a `weapon`). I've tried changing `weapon.wgt` to `self.weapon.wgt` but that doesn't seem to help.

See the pertinent parts of the code, leaving out the `attack` code because I don't think it's relevant to the question and will clutter up things, but I will if it's necessary.

I believe the code is a mess, so constructive critique will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
class Char(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        name = name
        hp = 300
        mp = 10
        strn = 1
        dmg = 1
        dex = 1
        armor = 0
        weapon = None

    attack_speed = dex

    intact_bones = ["right arm", "left arm", "right leg", "leg leg", "skull", "sternum", "nose"] # JUST ASSUME RIGHT SIDE IS PRIMARY SIDE FOR NOW

    broken_bones = [] ### define what to do per bone if bone is in this list

    dmg = strn * self.weapon.wgt


class Equip(object):
    wgt = 1
    desc = ""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class weapon(Equip):
    impact = 1
    sharp = 1

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

sword = weapon("Sword")
sword.wgt = 10
sword.impact = 6
sword.sharp = 7


dean.weapon = sword
dean.attack(hamilton)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to use `self`, as in your other `__init__` methods, to make attributes of the instance.

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = 300
    ...
    self.weapon = None
```

Also, I think the other attributes should also be instance attributes, i.e., set them in the `__init__` methods and use `self`, e.g. `self.wgt`, `self.impact`, `self.broken_bones`, etc.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Ok, I will try this when I get home and see if that fixes it. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, that did it. So, basically, I should generally put self in front of everything under __init__, it seems like?

Also, I'm now having a new problem with the same code. I'm fairly new to StackOverflow. Should I ask here or start a new thread?

Comment: @rrr45 Well, not _everything_, but everything that should be an attribute of the instance. If you declare some temporary variable you do not need to use `self`. Glad I could help. If you have a follow up question, you should post that as a new question, but maybe add a link to this question for context.

Answer (score 1):

Change the body of the constructor, because now you are assigning values to local variables rather than to the object variables:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = 300
    self.mp = 10
    self.strn = 1
    self.dmg = 1
    self.dex = 1
    self.armor = 0
    self.weapon = None
```