# Python variables with formulas all return value 1

Tags: python, variables, formula

(For reference, I asked a separate question--which was answered--regarding the same script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449188/class-attributes-not-passing-to-objects))

I'm learning Python, and this is my first program. I'm trying to create a very basic RPG-like game where you select a character, give that character a weapon, and then tell it to attack another character with damage based on formulas that use the stats of the character and the weapon.

I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I can't get my [variable] = ______ formulas to return anything other than 1, even though the variables used on the right side of the formula return the correct values independently.

This is what my "Char" (character) class looks like (sorry if I'm providing too much--trying not to leave anything out that might help):

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.hp = 300
    self.mp = 10
    self.strn = 1
    self.dex = 1
    self.armor = 0
    self.xp = 0
    self.items = []
    self.spells = []
    self.weapon = weapon


    self.attack_speed = self.dex

    self.intact_bones = ["right arm", "left arm", "right leg", "leg leg", 
                    "skull", "sternum", "nose"] # JUST ASSUME RIGHT SIDE 
                                                # IS PRIMARY SIDE FOR NOW

    self.broken_bones = [] ### define what to do per bone if bone is in this list

    self.base_dmg = self.strn * self.weapon.wgt
    self.break_bone_chance = (self.weapon.impact / 50) * 100
    self.bleed_chance = (self.weapon.sharp / 50) * 100

    self.strike_dmg = self.base_dmg # NEED TO ADD A RANDOM ELEMENT TO DAMAGE

def break_crit(self, target):
    print "checking break_crit" # ALL THESE PRINTS ARE TEMPORARY TO TEST THE VARIABLES
    print "self.break_bone_chance = %r" % self.break_bone_chance
    print "self.base_dmg = %r" % self.base_dmg
    print "self.strike_dmg = %r" % self.strike_dmg
    print "len(target.intact_bones) = %r" % len(target.intact_bones)
    print "self.weapon = %r" % self.weapon.name
    print "self.weapon.impact = %r" % self.weapon.impact
    print "self.weapon.wgt = %r" % self.weapon.wgt

    if (randint(1, 100) <= self.break_bone_chance) and (self.strike_dmg > 0) and (len(target.intact_bones) != 0):
        random.shuffle(target.intact_bones)
        target.new_broken_bone = target.intact_bones.pop()
        target.broken_bones.append(target.new_broken_bone)
        print "%s hit %s square in the %s with his %s, cracking his %s!" % (self, target, target.new_broken_bone, self.weapon, target.new_broken_bone)
        self.bleed_crit(target)
    else:
        self.bleed_crit(target)


def bleed_crit(self, target):
    if randint(1, 100) <= self.bleed_chance and self.strike_dmg > 0:
        pass
    else:
        pass # GO TO NEXT ACTION


def attack(self, target):
    ###self.strike_dmg = self.dmg - target.armor # NEED TO ADD A RANDOM ELEMENT TO DAMAGE###
    if self.strike_dmg > 0:
        target.hp -= self.strike_dmg
        print "%s hit %s for %s damage!" % (self.name, target.name, self.strike_dmg)
        self.break_crit(target)
    else: 
        print "%s's strike did no damage!" % self.name
```

My weapon class belongs to the Equip top-level class:

```
class Equip(object):
    wgt = 1

class weapon(Equip):
    impact = 1
    sharp = 1

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    desc = ""

chuck = weapon("Nun-chuck")
chuck.wgt = 3
chuck.impact = 6
chuck.sharp = 0

dean = Char("Dean")
dean.strn = 3
dean.dex = 8
dean.weapon = chuck
```

and then I'm just running a simple:
    dean.attack(hamilton) # hamilton is simply another Char

The thing that's confusing me is that when I have "print ........" to test the numbers, the numbers printed are correct. For instance, self.weapon.wgt is shown to be 3 as expected, self.strn prints as 3 expected, and self.weapon.impact prints as 6 as expected. However, in self.break_bone_chance, I've determined that self.weapon.impact is returning as 1 (by temporarily making self.break_bone_chance = only to self.weapon.impact), and self.strike_dmg also comes back as 1.

Again, I can provide the code for the "weapon" and "Char" in question if it will hlep, but I'm trying to leave off anything unnecessary. Does anything look wrong based on what I've provided here?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where does `weapon` *come* from?

Comment: Also, consider changing your `(self.weapon.impact / 50)` and `(self.weapon.sharp / 50)` to use floating point precision by using `50.0` instead of `50`. This way you will avoid issues when `self.weapon.impact` is an integer < 50 thus division by 50 yields 0, and the appriopriate chance is equal to `0*100`.

Comment: Ok, I added more of the code to show how I have the weapon stuff set up. Additionally, I added the floating precision, but that didn't fix the problem. Any advice based on what I've added?

Answer (score 0):

I only looked at this quickly, but kroolik's comment is probably the problem you're running into - integer division truncates.

You can change `50` to `50.0`, which will fix this, or you could use the `from future import division` future import to cause all of your divisions to be floating point division by default. Then you would need to use `//` if you ever actually wanted integer division.