# How to give an object (has-a) an object of another class

Tags: python, class, object

So I was having some trouble with some code I'm doing for a basic game that I'm writing in my learning of Python (original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469963/python-variables-with-formulas-all-return-value-1) if it helps).

After a lot of playing around with it, I realized my problem. I don't actually know how to do a "has-a" when trying to let one object (a character) "have" an object of another class (such as a weapon).

If I want, say a Char (character) called dean to do an action specific to the weapon he has. How would I give that object (the Char dean) an object of class "Weapon"?

Thank you.

Edit:

I've found that I can do this by passing the "Weapon" in question as an argument. i.e.:

dean = Char("Dean", hanzo_blade)

Then having Char **init** with (self, name, weapon).

However, I want the user to choose, from a selection, which weapon the character gets. So I'm not sure if the content of the Char(_____) can be determined on a dynamic basis from user input. If it's possible, how can I do that? If not, what do I do?

Thanks again.

Edit 2: Here is the pertinent code:

```
class Char(object):


    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 300
        self.mp = 10
        self.strn = 1
        self.dex = 1
        self.armor = 0
        self.xp = 0
        self.items = []
        self.spells = []
        self.weapon = sword() # Assume sword is the default. Alternatively, how might I let this default to nothing?

class Weapon(Equip):
    impact = 1
    sharp = 1

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

hanzo_blade = Weapon("Hanzo Blade")
hanzo_blade.wgt = 3
hanzo_blade.impact = 1 
hanzo_blade.sharp = 9


dean = Char("Dean")
dean.strn = 3
dean.dex = 8
```

If hanzo_blade is one option, how could I let the player, for instance, select that Weapon for the Char dean?

Comment: what's wrong with simply `self.dean = Dean()`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting. I didn't want to flood the page, but would it help if I pasted the whole script?

Comment: What's wrong with `dean = Char('Dean', weapon_the_user_picked)`?

Comment: user--That's what I'm thinking but I'm not sure how to make weapon_the_user_picked actually reflect the weapon the user picked. Forgive my noobness.

Comment: So this is a question about processing user input, and not about how to implement has-a relationships?

Comment: Well, it's about the combination of the two. I don't know how to implement either properly. Additionally, I just added the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware of the `raw_input` builtin? (`input` in Python 3)

```
# We assume we already have sword, fists, and stern_glare objects
# representing weapons.
weapons = {'sword': sword, 'fists': fists, 'stern glare': stern_glare}

# Prompt for a choice, and keep prompting until you get a valid choice.
# You'll probably want a more user-friendly prompt.
valid_choice = False
while not valid_choice:
    weapon_choice = raw_input('Select your weapon')
    valid_choice = weapon_choice in weapons

# Create the character.
dean = Char('Dean', weapons[weapon_choice])
```

Comment: Ok I think this is going to help a ton. Quick question, though. Why do I need weapons[weapon_choice] as opposed to simply weapon_choice?

Comment: @rrr45: `weapon_choice` is a string. If a string is a satisfactory representation of the character's weapon, that may be fine, but you'll most likely want to give the weapon attributes that shouldn't be forced into a string.

Comment: so in the "weapons" dict(?), would sword, fists, and stern_glare be predefined objects of Weapon type?

(Also, I'm in Py2, not 3, if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Probably. Alternatively, they might be subclasses of Weapon, in which case you'd instantiate the selected class and pass the instance to the `Char` constructor.

Comment: "in which case you'd instantiate the selected class and pass the instance to the Char constructor" -- Ok, not sure what that means, but I think I've got enough fuel here to figure it out. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Ok, I'm working on this now, and I have one more question if you can help. Where would I put the above weapons dict? Does it belong in a class or something? Or does it just go out on its own? Thanks for all your help.